# How to paste items of a list in aplotly title?

Tags: r, r-plotly

Hello how can I paste multiple items into a plotly Title. This is my code:

```
    timestep = 2
    lst_raitings_hy =  c("BB", "B")

fig_hy <- plot_ly(x = summaries_hy$maturity)
fig_hy <- fig_hy %>% add_trace(y = summaries_hy$mean_yield, name = "Mean", type="scatter", mode="lines+markers", marker=list(color = "rgba(0,100,0,1)", line = list(color = "rgba(0,100,0,1)", shape = "spline")))
fig_hy <- fig_hy %>% add_trace(y = summaries_hy$perc_005, name = "0.5% Percentile", type="scatter", fill='tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,70,100,0.5)',mode = 'lines', line = list(color = "transparent", shape = "spline"))
fig_hy <- fig_hy %>% add_trace(y = summaries_hy$perc_05, name = "5% Percentile", type="scatter", fill='tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,50,100,0.6)', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = "transparent", shape = "spline"))
fig_hy <- fig_hy %>% add_trace(y = summaries_hy$perc_75, name = "75% Percentile", type="scatter", fill='tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,40,100,0.4)', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = "transparent", shape = "spline"))
fig_hy <- fig_hy %>% add_trace(y = summaries_hy$perc_995, name = "99.5% Percentile", type="scatter", fill='tonexty', fillcolor='rgba(0,10,100,0.1)', mode = 'lines', line = list(color = "transparent", shape = "spline"))
fig_hy <- fig_hy %>%    layout(
  title = paste("Worst Case HighYield SpotSpread Curve timestep", timestep, lst_raitings_hy),
  xaxis = list(title = "Maturity"),
  yaxis = list(title = "Spot Spread", tickformat=" .2%")
)
 
fig_hy
```

Now as you cans see I would like plotly to paste both raitings in the title but it does not work. If I only choose one it all works fine.
Thank you!:)

Answer (score 0):

I assume your expected output for the title is: `"Worst Case HighYield SpotSpread Curve timestep 2 BB B"`. The problem is that the way you are using paste you are pasting the first two strings to the vector of strings `lst_raitings_hy` which has `length =2`. The result is two strings: `"Worst Case HighYield SpotSpread Curve timestep 2 BB" "Worst Case HighYield SpotSpread Curve timestep 2 B"`. To avoid this and receive a single string for your title with the aforementioned expected result paste the elements of vector `lst_raitings_hy` together first and combine it with the other strings:

```
paste("Worst Case HighYield SpotSpread Curve timestep", timestep, paste(lst_raitings_hy, collapse = " "))
```

Comment: You nailed it! Thank you so much! :)